# The point of using a scripting language

Tags: scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we use scripts in development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/why-do-we-use-scripts-in-development)

Im wondering, why do people use scripting languages like Lua or Python in game engines when we can use CLI/C++ or C# interpreters?

Comment: And [When would I use “scripts” or “scripting” in a game, as opposed to the core language?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17292/when-would-i-use-scripts-or-scripting-in-a-game-as-opposed-to-the-core-lang)

Answer (score 1):

There are few advantages:

1. scripting languages can save lots of development time
2. the code can be "cleaner" and easier to modify
3. no need to recompile the code after each edit

And as the engine itself is usually written in compiled language, performance is usually not an issue and when it is you can port only the bottleneck code to C++, etc. and call it from your scripting language.